# How to capitalize 1st letter (ignoring non a-z) with regex in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

There are tons of posts regarding how to capitalize the first letter with C#, but I specifically am struggling how to do this when ignoring prefixed non-letter characters and tags inside them. **Eg,**

`<style=blah>capitalize the word, 'capitalize'</style>`

How to ignore *potential* <> tags (or non-letter chars before it, like asterisk `*`) and the contents within them, THEN capitalize "capitalize"?

I tried:

```
public static string CapitalizeFirstCharToUpperRegex(string str)
{
    // Check for empty string.  
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        return string.Empty;

    // Return char and concat substring. 
    // Start @ first char, no matter what (avoid <tags>, etc)
    string pattern = @"(^.*?)([a-z])(.+)";

    // Extract middle, then upper 1st char
    string middleUpperFirst = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "$2");
    middleUpperFirst = CapitalizeFirstCharToUpper(str); // Works

    // Inject the middle back in
    string final = $"$1{middleUpperFirst}$3";
    return Regex.Replace(str, pattern, final);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Input: `<style=foo>first non-tagged word 1st char upper</style>`

Expected output: `<style=foo>First non-tagged word 1st char upper</style>`

Comment: @GalAbra but this would change `<style=blah>capitalize` to `<Style=blah>capitalize`, and this does not seem to be what OP wants

Comment: How about [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yep, I originally thought that and, indeed, had results such as <Style> with a capital S, breaking my style (ending up not very stylish, might I add!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
<[^<>]*>|(?<!\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L}*)
```

The regex does the following:

- `<[^<>]*>` - matches `<`, any 0+ chars other than `<` and `>` and then `>`
- `|` - or
- `(?<!\p{L})` - finds a position not immediately preceded with a letter
- `(\p{L})` - captures into Group 1 any letter
- `(\p{L}*)`  - captures into Group 2 any 0+ letters (that is necessary if you want to lowercase the rest of the word).

Then, check if Group 2 matched, and if yes, capitalize the first group value and lowercase the second one, else, return the whole value:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"<[^<>]*>|(?<!\p{L})(\p{L})(\p{L}*)", m =>
                m.Groups[1].Success ? 
                  m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() + m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower() :
                  m.Value);
```

If you do not need to lowercase the rest of the word, remove the second group and the code related to it:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"<[^<>]*>|(?<!\p{L})(\p{L})", m =>
                m.Groups[1].Success ? 
                  m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper() : m.Value);
```

To only replace the first occurrence using this approach, you need to set a flag and reverse it once the first match is found:

```
var s = "<style=foo>first non-tagged word 1st char upper</style>";
var found = false;
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"<[^<>]*>|(?<!\p{L})(\p{L})", m => {
            if (m.Groups[1].Success && !found) { 
                found = !found;
                return m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper();
            } else {
                return m.Value;
            }
        });
Console.WriteLine(result); // => <style=foo>First non-tagged word 1st char upper</style>
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/8bHzIA).

Comment: Very close! Cheers for the detailed explanations, too. I noticed `Every Word Instead Of Just First Shows` (which also messes up conjunctions, like can't == `Can'T`). Also, add `.Value` before the `.ToUpper()` for syntax ~ What would be the best way to make only the first matched a-z char uppercase it?

Comment: @dylanh724 Fixed `.Value`. If you mean to capitalize the first letter in a chunk of non-whitespace chars use `<[^<>]*>|(?<!\p{L})(\p{L})(\S*)` regex and use `+ m.Groups[2].Value` or `+ m.Groups[2].Value.ToLower()` in the replacement.

Comment: Rather -- the first block found, then nothing more~). Or in your example, I could probably but a bool isMatched = true, then only make the value to upper that once, else just add the value (which would be pretty ghetto). Some way to make it stop after the first one found. An example is...
`<style=foo>something like this</style>` => Expected result would be `<style=foo>Something like this</style>` (only the 1st chunk upper'd). **EDIT:** Updated OP with a more-clear example.

Comment: I'll be able to test it tomorrow! I'll edit this with some useful context after test :) Thanks for the wonderful example and reference. Since the example seemed to work, I will mark as resolved with this answer!

Answer (score 1):

Using look-behind regex feature you can match the first 'capitalize' without > parenthesis and then you can capitalize the output.
The regex is the following:

```
(?<=<.*>)\w+
```

It will match the first word after the > parenthesis